# Mouse and Keyboard Event Detection when Application is Minimized

Tags: c#, mouseevent, keyboard-events

My program counts and save how much time the user is spending on applications. For example, if he is using Microsoft Word, time is counting on M. Word, thats done, but i need to know when he stop typing or moving the mouse (AFK) to stop counting.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe there is other way.

Comment: These events are available in DOM like for typing you can use the .keypress(), you can catch those events and implement your logic there.

Answer (score 0):

Also i have a timer... so my idea is something like this (just making my point, is C#):

```
short afk = 0;

onTimer_tick{
   afk += 1;

   if(afk == 500){
      timerInterval = 0; //(stop counting) 
   }

}

onMouseMove or KeyPress //(outside the frame, in any application){
    timerInterval = 1000; ///every 1 second restart
    afk = 0;
}
```

**i dont know how to work with mouse or keyboard outside the frame**